# TypeError: QFileDialog.history(self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QFileDialog'

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using PyQT and have already instantiated the class for my GUI. I'm trying to find the history of files opened in my GUI.

```
def plotButtonClicked(self):
    lst = QFileDialog.history(self)
```

The above `def` is called by another function which creates the whole GUI. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: QFileDialog.history(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QFileDialog'
```

Funny thing is I've been using the `QFileDialog` in other functions. Here's one instance where it works:

```
fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
```

So why isn't the `history()` method not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileDialog.history` is not a *classmethod* (also called *static* function in C++).
For you to be able to call the method, you'd have to either pass the class as first argument (as the error says) or instantiate `QFileDialog` before calling the method.

The reason why `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` works is because it's a *classmethod* (static method), and as the doc says, it's a [convenience static function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName).

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot.

Comment: @iSplasher   pls give an example